# Page content showing up before header in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just finishing this wordpress site for a client and now I am deploying it so they can edit it in the backend and for some reason the content is showing up above my header(as shown below) and I am not sure why.

[image]

I put my code in the wordpress backend

[image]

this is my code with my content commented out:

```
<?php

   /**
 * Template Name: About Us
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Creativeforces
 * @since  Creativeforces Group 1.0
 */
 ?>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zip Zap Zop Enrichment | About Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/css/about.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>


<header>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
         <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</header>

   <?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- <div class="container">
   <h3 class="text-center text-style">Who Is Zip Zap Zop Enrichment</h3>
   <hr>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-7">
   <p> Sisters <strong>Maja Miletich</strong> and <strong>April Rasmussen</strong> grew up with a brother, Zack, who is on the autism spectrum. Though very high functioning, for a time he was totally nonverbal. April and Maja became experts on Zack’s needs in order to help support him as he learned to interact with the world around him; a world that was very difficult to access. However, as Zach grew up, he found his voice through writing and has maintained a blog (Clashing with Life) for more than eight years!</p> <p>It was this ability to communicate that gave Zach greater confidence, gave him a way to interact with a world he had been previously cut off from, and gave him access to information so he could grow and learn. Zach was later able to attend college, study information technology, and has a steady job that he takes great pride in. </p>
   <p>Both women were inspired by their brother and both decided to pursue careers in education: Maja studied early childhood development with a focus on special needs, and April pursued secondary language arts with a focus on English language learners. Zip Zap Zop originally began in 2011 after Maja, a graduate of The Second City Improv program, was working in a special needs classroom. She found that many of her improv techniques engaged students who were otherwise unreachable. April became a credentialed English teacher in 2008 and has seen the consequences of high school level students who are not comfortable communicating, whether that be students with special needs or students learning English as a second language.</p>
   <p><strong>Zip Zap Zop Enrichment</strong> believes communication, both verbal and non-verbal, is the gateway for all learning, for all students, regardless of subject area. Our goal is to improve communication skills and thus provide greater access for students with special needs in an inclusive classroom, but also improve learning outcomes for all students. Our teaching philosophy is that a truly good teaching practice benefits all students, so by finding ways to support and include students with special needs, all students benefit as well. </p>
   </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <img src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/maja3.png" alt="">
  </div>
  </div>
  </div> -->



   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

for some reason my homepage content is showing up perfectly normal and I haven't done anything different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your header.php and footer.php files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the point at which you call `get_header()`. You're looping through your content before that call takes place. Reposition the WordPress loop (`while ( have_posts()...`) beneath `get_header()`.

You're also placing your document head in the template file when it should be part of header.php.

As you've only posted the code for your About Us template it's not possible to say why the homepage would behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your includes or requires, please make sure that your include or require is positioned correctly in your code please see php manual on includes and requires. Here is a link to shed some light on the subject
[Inlcudes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: This is not an answer and would be better as a comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this is the wordpress loop that is grabbing your post content and it looks like in your code the_content() is located within the header and before the wp get_header() is called.

If you can't sort it out here, there is a wordpress stack exchange https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ that might be a better place for this question.

```
 <header>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
             <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </header>
 <?php get_header(); ?>
```